# Why does my data not seem to be aligned?

Tags: c++, alignment, intrinsics

I'm trying to figure out how to best pre-calculate some sin and cosine values, store them in aligned blocks, and then use them later for SSE calculations:

At the beginning of my program, I create an object with member:

```
static __m128 *m_sincos;
```

then I initialize that member in the constructor:

```
m_sincos = (__m128*) _aligned_malloc(Bins*sizeof(__m128), 16);
for (int t=0; t<Bins; t++)
  m_sincos[t] = _mm_set_ps(cos(t), sin(t), sin(t), cos(t));
```

When I go to use m_sincos, I run into three problems:
-The data does not seem to be aligned

```
movaps xmm0, m_sincos[t] //crashes
movups xmm0, m_sincos[t] //does not crash
```

-The variables do not seem to be correct

```
movaps result, xmm0 // returns values that are not what is in m_sincos[t]
//Although, putting a watch on m_sincos[t] displays the correct values
```

-What really confuses me is that this makes everything work (but is too slow):

```
__m128 _sincos = m_sincos[t];
movaps xmm0, _sincos
movaps result, xmm0
```

Comment: I just did a sizeof(__m128), sizeof(m_sincos[t]), and sizeof(result) and they all returned "16"

Comment: using _mm_malloc instead of _aligned_malloc seems to function the exact same, and as far as memory locations, when I initialize m_sincos, the address is: 0x260e2720, and then when I go to use it, the address is still 0x260e2720... does that help?

Comment: hmm, try putting assert statement before each load to check for alignment and instead of assembly, can you try _mm_load_ps intrinsic?

Comment: @aaa - used _mm_store_ps(result,m_sincos[t]); and this works fine, and returns the appropriate values! As far as an assert statement checking for alignment, do  you just want me to check the sizeof(m_sincos[t])? because I'm doing that and they're always size 16, but I'm really curious why I can't use the assembly code, what the difference between the intrinsic and assembly is?

Comment: This duplication seems like a terrible idea unless your table is quite small or you use the same `__m128` from memory repeatedly.  It's very cheap to do an 8B load of `[c, s]` and shuffle it to get `[c, s, s, c]`, and will probably pay for itself in reduced cache misses.  Inline asm is just *bad* for this compared to letting the compiler do the indexing (so it can increment something in a loop by 16).  If you use asm, write how loops or functions in asm, not fragments.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`m_sincos[t]` is a C expression.  In an assembly instruction, however, (`__asm`?), it's interpreted as an x86 addressing mode, with a completely different result.  For example, VS2008 SP1 compiles:

```
movaps xmm0, m_sincos[t]
```

into: (see the disassembly window when the app crashes in debug mode)

```
movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [t]
```

That interpretation attempts to copy a 128-bit value stored at the address of the variable `t` into xmm0.  `t`, however, is a 32-bit value at a likely unaligned address.  Executing the instruction is likely to cause an alignment failure, and would get you incorrect results at the odd case where `t`'s address is aligned.

You could fix this by using an appropriate x86 addressing mode.  Here's the slow but clear version:

```
__asm mov eax, m_sincos                  ; eax <- m_sincos
__asm mov ebx, dword ptr t
__asm shl ebx, 4                         ; ebx <- t * 16 ; each array element is 16-bytes (128 bit) long
__asm movaps xmm0, xmmword ptr [eax+ebx] ; xmm0 <- m_sincos[t]
```

---

**Sidenote:**

When I put this in a complete program, something odd occurs:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main()
{
    static __m128 *m_sincos;
    int Bins = 4;

    m_sincos = (__m128*) _aligned_malloc(Bins*sizeof(__m128), 16);
    for (int t=0; t<Bins; t++) {
        m_sincos[t] = _mm_set_ps(cos((float) t), sin((float) t), sin((float) t), cos((float) t));
        __asm movaps xmm0, m_sincos[t];
        __asm mov eax, m_sincos
        __asm mov ebx, t
        __asm shl ebx, 4
        __asm movaps xmm0, [eax+ebx];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When you run this, if you keep an eye on the registers window, you might notice something odd.  Although the results are correct, `xmm0` is getting the correct value *before* the `movaps` instruction is executed.  How does that happen?

A look at the generated assembly code shows that `_mm_set_ps()` loads the sin/cos results into `xmm0`, then saves it to the memory address of `m_sincos[t]`.  But the value remains there in `xmm0` too. `_mm_set_ps` is an 'intrinsic', not a function call; it does not attempt to restore the values of registers it uses after it's done.

If there's a lesson to take from this, it might be that when using the SSE intrinsic functions, use them throughout, so the compiler can optimize things for you.  Otherwise, if you're using inline assembly, use that throughout too.

Comment: Wow, that's probably the best answer that I've read in all of my searching, thanks for the clear explanation! So, if I wanted to use assembly throughout, does that mean that I would have to do the shl instruction to move to the correct position in my array just as you do with the intrinsics? Thanks very much!!

Comment: Yes, you need to multiply the array index by 16 to get the correct offset.  x86 has a number of addressing modes that multiply indices for you, avoiding the need to shift explicitly.  I could not, however, find one that would multiply by 16.  Doesn't mean there isn't one, just that I didn't find it.  An alternative would be to increment the index by 16 on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

You should always use the instrinsics or even just turn it on and leave them, rather than explicitly coding it in. This is because __asm is not portable to 64bit code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I was just reading into that when you posted!